Getting error of null when using prompt with tuned model in Vertex AI
I used the tuning with gemini-1.0-pro-002 with basic log data. the tuning completed and when I use the prompt to query the model, I get a null error as below
jsonl structure used for tuning
{"messages": [{"role": "system", "content": "you should give the detailed explanation of the logs"}, {"role": "user", "content": "2017-11-29 19:22:31,581 [main] INFO  (LoggingHelper.java:23) - This is info  log ...\n 2017-11-29 19:22:31,581 [main] WARN  (LoggingHelper.java:26) - This is warn log ...\n 2017-11-29 19:22:31,581 [main] ERROR (LoggingHelper.java:27) - This is error log... \n 2017-11-29 19:22:31,582 [main] FATAL (LoggingHelper.java:28) - This is fatal log ...\n 2017-11-29 19:23:44,026 [main] DEBUG (LoggingHelper.java:19) - This is debug log..\n 2017-11-29 19:23:44,028 [main] INFO  (LoggingHelper.java:23) - This is info  log ...\n 2017-11-29 19:23:44,028 [main] WARN  (LoggingHelper.java:26) - This is warn log ...\n 2017-11-29 19:23:44,028 [main] ERROR (LoggingHelper.java:27) - This is error log... \n 2017-11-29 19:25:15,181 [main] ERROR (LogginHelperOps.java:15) - Sorry, something wrong in your calculation!\n java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero\n   at com.itos.LogginHelperOps.divide(LogginHelperOps.java:23)\n   at com.itos.LogginHelperOps.main(LogginHelperOps.java:13)\n 2017-11-29 19:23:44,028 [main] INFO  (LoggingHelper.java:23) - This is info  log ...\n 2017-11-29 19:23:44,028 [main] INFO  (LoggingHelper.java:23) - This is info  log ...\n 2017-11-29 19:23:44,028 [main] INFO  (LoggingHelper.java:23) - This is info  log ...\n 2017-11-29 19:23:44,028 [main] INFO  (LoggingHelper.java:23) - This is info  log ..."}, {"role": "model", "content": "#code#: LogginHelperOps.java:15\n#dbtables#:projectx_maths\n #solution#: The value should not be less than 1 for height column in projectx_maths table "}]}

ERROR

What am I missing here.
Any suggestions will be of much help?

HI , could you please elaborate more on the use cases you are following ?

I wanted to use api gateway to upload a file to S3.
The bucket name  had to be from the header of the REST call. The file name from the URL of the API gateway itself
eg: https://appl.com/files/{proxy+}  ||
header X-app-name - bucket name  ||
proxy+  - should be the path and file name should be uploaded
